# Example of customisations with rpmrc?

Tags: configuration, rpm

Can someone please share examples of when and/or where the rpmrc files under the path (`/etc/rpmrc and ~/.rpmrc`) are used by a system administrator ?

Evident from the question but stating it for clarity - I am noob s/w eng and have no experience with Linux, much lesser with CentOS. I have scoured the internet for when, where and why the rpmrc is used but did not find much. (perhaps I am not looking for the right thing!)

I am looking to understand what kind of system wide customizations might an administrator put under `/etc/rpmrc` and what customizations might an administrator put under `~/.rpmrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `/etc/rpmrc` is old and obsoleted. Modern systems use `/etc/rpm/macros.*` or even `/usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/`.

You should not touch it. Not even as a user. Not even as a packager or DevOps guy. People creating the distribution put there the distribution default.

Nearly all macros **do not affect runtime**. They are read and interpreted during the build of the package and cannot be changed later. Therefore there should be no need to alter it.

You may want to change some macros on the machine where you build your custom packages. Even then you should not touch it. For such case you can - and should - use `~/.rpmmacros`.

You should not define new macros there. When you use such macro in your SPEC file, then the package cannot be built on a different machine. When you need to define a new macro you should do that at the top of the SPEC file.

And some good example?

It is good to re-define the existing macro. E.g., `_smp_mflags`. If you check how it is defined (`rpm --showrc` is your friend) then you will find that it pass to make -l option based on top of your CPU core. But the upper limit is 16 cores. Now, imagine, that you are building some scientific package, which needs a lot of parallelisms. And you have a machine with 128 cores. You are not using the full power you have! You improve the performance of building your rpm package when you put

```
_smp_mflags -l128
```

in the `~/.rpmmacros`.

Comment: Ah. really helpful ! thnx